# how to sum last x rows from a column? Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to sum values in column H for the last 52 rows with a formula, starting in H3. Rows will be added regularly.

```
=query("H" & IF( COUNT(H3:H)-52+2<3,3, COUNT(H3:H)-52+2) & ":H" & COUNT(H3:H)+2,"select sum(H)",-1)
```

EDIT:

This is also not working, why? If I use concatenate I see "H5:H57"

```
=sum("H"& trim(IF( COUNT(H3:H)-52+2<3,3, COUNT(H3:H)-52+2)) & ":H" & trim(COUNT(H3:H)+2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a cell reference as a string, but you need to convert it to a cell reference.

You are looking for [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en):

```
=sum(indirect("H"& trim(IF( COUNT(H3:H)-52+2<3,3, COUNT(H3:H)-52+2)) & ":H" & trim(COUNT(H3:H)+2)))
```